# Researching the effect of bookmakers' odds on predictions

Tags: regression, predictive-models, odds-ratio, scoring-rules

I did an experiment in which I asked 150 people to predict the likelihood of the home team winning eight upcoming NBA playoff matches. Subjects were separated in four different treatments in a 2x2 design. The aim was to find the influence of different stakes on their answer, and more importantly if they significantly between treatment groups. I codified the treatment groups as binary variables and removed fans from any individual matchup from the data. Then I ran a regression with their prediction as dependent variable and the binary treatments as independent variables plus their interaction. I found some mixed results and I want to know whether the bookmakers' odds played a significant role in their answer. You can imagine that if the stakes get higher people are more likely to try and collect information to give a better prediction. To do this I collected the odds from 8 major bookmaking companies and aggregated them and computed an average in a probability score, for instance the result would be 0.5 (most odds were around this level with 0.47 being the minimum and 0.55 the maximum).

I then created a new variable that takes the absolute difference between any given subject prediction and the computed odds, call this variable absdiffx. Now I would like to find out two things:

1. Do the odds significantly influence reported prediction? To do this I ran a simple regression with their prediction as dependent variable and absdiffx as the independent variable.
2. Do the treatment effects significantly influence how close people report predictions to the bookmakers' odds? To do this I regressed absdiffx as the dependent variable and the treatment effects as independent dummy variables.

My questions are whether my attempts to answer my goals are statistically viable. Could I combine both into one regression model? I tried this but in 6/8 cases absdiffx seems very significant, almost too much. Could this be because most bookmakers' odds are around 0.5?

How would you undertake such a research? I look forward to hearing your insights, if there are any questions let me know!

Comment: Philip Tetlock is widely regarded as an expert on how the nuts and bolts of expert forecasting works, e.g., his 2015 book might help in gaining greater traction, *Superforecasting: The Art and Science of Prediction*.